# Run a python script in a different environment from a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, environment, execute

I have a main Jupyter Notebook file that operates on a Slicer kernel. It opens slicer and makes the user save the labels. I know what to run a deep learning model in PyTorch on a Python 3 kernel. To do this, I first need to transform the labels to the format that I need which is tiff.

I managed to do it in Spyder.

```
import numpy as np
from imageio import imwrite
import os

## define where the masks are saved as a .npy
labelpath="../temp/label.npy" # changed for privacy
## define path where the new masks should be saved as .tiff files
labelpathsave="../temp/" # changed for privacy

## open the object
label=np.load(labelpath)

number_files=np.shape(label)[0]

for i in range(0, number_files):
   string="label"+str(i+1)+".tiff"
   labelpath=os.path.join(labelpathsave, string)
   currentlabel=label[i]
   imwrite(labelpath, currentlabel)
```

This above works, but trying to execute this python file in the Jupyter Notebook.

```
execfile('../scripts/Maja/transform_label.py') # changed for privacy
```

I get "ImportError: No module named imageio".

How can I make it work execute "transform_label.py" given that it runs in a different environment?

(I need to do it in separate files because I cannot get the PyTorch package to work on a Slicer kernel)

Comment: I am running print(os.system('python /Users/.../scripts/Maja/transform_label.py')) on a jupyter notebook with a python 3 kernel and it works perfectly. Gives me a '0'. When I run it from the slicer jupyter kernel I get '6' and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

## installing imageio

**for python 2**

```
pip install imageio --user
```

**for python 3**

```
pip3 install imageio --user
```

**For Conda Environments**

```
conda install -c conda-forge imageio
```

**NOTE** : Must check first which version of python is being running on Notebook.

**After installation**
(*The installation includes all necessary lib that are needed to import*.)
Rerun the above code!!!...

Comment: Different environments sometimes does not support your .py file. Lets say a file already executing in python 3 with slicer kernel will show import errors. It can be solved by adding some lib required for each environment such as conda lib or spyder lib.

Comment: Thanks. Slicer operates on a slicer kernel 4.10. I cannot install some packages on it. This is why I wanna call the script from the slicer notebook but tell it to execute on a different environment.

Comment: On which packages installation are you facing difficulty? Let me help you to solve the problem by sticking with its true nature due to which there is error. Choose the second option i.e. changing environment otherwise.

Comment: pytorch will not install on a slicer kernel

Comment: kernel-template.json should be used for installed versions, too. So, maybe that's an issue, too. Does everything work if you use Slicer-4.10?
Does "/usr/local/bin/python/jupyter-kernelspec" executable exist?
Can you find a kernel-template.json file somewhere in /Applications/Slicer.app/Contents/Extensions-27501 folder or in its subfolders?

Comment: First run this comand

"conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch"  ..........
then,
"pip install pytorch-toolbelt"
use this to install necessary tools for pytorch. Create a new environment after it and run the above code

Comment: https://discourse.slicer.org/t/using-slicerjupyter-with-python-packages-outside-of-slicer-distribution/6162 the problem is this one. In the end we will use python 3 interpreter but inside slicer not slicer notebook which is sad :(. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the script is not working because the imageio module cannot be found.
Have you tried to save imageio in a directory where you know that other modules can be loaded by Jupyter notebooks? Maybe it is just a matter of the directories, where jupyter notebooks looks for modules.

Or it could also be that for spyder (if you use it through the anaconda distribution) had this imageio package preinstalled. So you could also try and just check in jupyter if you have the package installed there.

Comment: This is a slicer problem. Some packages cannot be loaded for a slicer notebook. I would like to tell python in the slicer notebook to execute that file but using a different environment. I just need the output created by that code.